# Snk file & Delay Signing

Tags: .net, snk, sn.exe

I am working with a set of delay signed assemblies which I am able to install and load from GAC after skipping verification (sn -Vr * ...

Since Delaysigning as a process requires only the public key file

1. sn -k keys.snk (both Public & Private keys)
2. sn -p keys.snk pkey.snk (only public key)
3. Add pkey.snk to project properties and check 'Delay Sign Only'
4. sn -v  (displays assembly is delay signed)
5. sn -e   (extract pkey)
6. fc   (no diff found)

I found that the first [160 bytes of the SNK file is the PKey](http://en.csharp-online.net/.NET_CLR_Components%E2%80%94Public_Keys_and_Assemblies)... and rest 436 bytes represent private key.

While for development purposes sn-Vr or sn -R keys.snk (new public/private key pair to replace the one delay-signed with) should suffice, I'm curious to know if extracting the public key from an assembly and pairing it with your own *private key* would work...

This could be a potential security loop hole (as assemblies are looked up with public key tokens)...  No wonder there's no built in tool in .Net framework / SDK that allows this.

Is there a place where the entire SNK file structure (file format) is documented?  Can this approach, in general, work?  What do you think?

Comment: What exactly is the security hole? Your description is unclear.

Comment: I said "potential"...  Not an expert there...  Top of my head: You could pretend that somebody else's public key is yours...  And your public key tokens would match..  If I had security rights assigned / verification skipped based on public key token, you could potentially take advantage...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be concerned that someone will generate a random keypair, replace the public key in the keypair with the public key from a different assembly, then sign their own assemblies to have that public key.

This will not work.
THe public key in a keypair is derived cryptographically from the private key, and the assembly is signed with a value that can only be computed using the correct *private* key.
Each private key will generate a different signature, and they're not interchangeable.

For more information, see [here](http://www.csharp411.com/net-assembly-faq-part-3-strong-names-and-signing/).

Comment: @SLaks:  Thanks for your reply...  Well, that was not a security question :)  Or at least it wasn't intended...  You need only 'public key' to delay sign...  I don't have access to the "production" private key...  In order for me to even load the delay signed assembly, I need to skip verification and stuff...  I'm just wondering if I can re-sign the assembly using an SNK file that has "release" public key and my own home cooked private key...
In other words, I'm looking for ways to replace a public key in a SNK file that has both keys...

Comment: @SLaks:  That's true when you directly sign...  Because compiler computes hashes with your private key...  Not when you delay sign...  You don't need private key...  Also, sn has option to recompute hashes sn -Ra...  I understand this as you could replace hashes in the assembly too with new ones.

Comment: As I thought I explained, no.  You can't mix-and-match key parts like that.

Comment: If you're asking whether you can re-sign the assembly with the production _private_ key, yes you can.